# Tensorflow inception without bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I tried this image recognition tutorial from tensorflow site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining
and it worked succefully with bazel bu command line
Is it possible to call this inception model programmatically using bazel or by a python script for example so I can feed it with images easily

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a bit? The tutorial itself is running a Python script to do the training, so if I'm understanding your question you could just modify that for your purposes.

Comment: To use this tutorial, Ihave to use bazel command: 
    bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image      which is not a python script, it is a command line, I want to predict an image using a python script so I can use the prediction in other part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generated files under tmp directory and write a python script to load the model and generate predictions.

Also, it is advisable to keep the files in a directory other than tmp folder as the contents of the folders can be flushed away.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys


image_path = sys.argv[1]
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

#loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.strip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile("/tmp/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tmp/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image data as input to the graph an get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0':image_data})
    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.2f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Comment: thx, I will try this script tonight, I am using Tensorflow 1.0+